# How do I get ArcGIS tiles to display a single layer when multiple layers are available?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps v7 to display layers from an ArcGIS server. The server displays multiple layers as one, but I would like to only display a single layer.

Suppose a map service has the layers: Topographic Info (0), Places Info (5), and Citations(10)

I write code to get a tile like so:

```
var source = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
        uriConstructor: function( tile ) {
            return baseUrl + "/tile/" + tile.levelOfDetail 
                        + "/" + tile.y + "/" + tile.x;
        }
    });
```

Which would procdure a URL like this:
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/12/1528/1218

Is it possible to have the generated tile only display information regarding a single layer, such as Topographic Info (0)?

I tried variations of things like ?layers=0 in the query string, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

no you can not. it's a tiled service. it just returns you a static image (jpg, png, etc). if you want to be able to separate the layers, these layers or info have be to in different tiled services.